# Windows 10 Home C:\ 1TB Disk cleanup resulting Windows Update cleanup 3,99TB

Tags: windows-10, disk-cleanup

Have anyone seen this?

> Windows 10 Home C:\ 1TB Disk cleanup resulting on Windows Update cleanup 3,99TB

[image]

On the right above the blue, you have the point, Windows Update cleaning 3,99Tt = 3,99Tb or TB.

I did check it several times, and it's true ... but, didn't so far dare to tick that one for cleaning, other regular ones only.

So, is there any explanation for this suggested 3,99TB Windows Update cleaning on an 1TB disk?

I guess some kind of bug. Should I dare to tick it for cleaning without any risk of something weird happening?

Edit 20.08.2016 18:00 (GMT+3):

For info, I didn't anymore get this repeated, nor had a chance to try to cleanup the 3,99TB and see what may have been happening, maybe better this way ... The result for the cleanup suggestions were quite normal today, don't know why, and now I did delete all the suggested unnecessary items totalling ab. 10GB.

Comment: A screen shot would help us understand your question.
StackExchange uses Imgur for image storage. Upload your image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/EVw63di.jpg) what you're talking about?

Comment: OK, here you have a screenshot on the case -> http://imgur.com/a/sch8d , sorry, in finnish, I think most is self-explanatory, but on the right above the blue, you have the point, Windows Update cleaning 3,99Tt = 3,99Tb or TB.

Comment: @DavidPostill OK, thanks for the edit and screenshot embed.

Comment: @PeteVfi You're welcome. Hopefully the edit will help to get it reopened :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this strange behaviour did vanish quite soon by itself!? Not seen it anymore at all on any machine ...

Comment: Just saying... you are not the only one... my friend just posted something similar on FB so I guess its a bug.

Comment: @echo_salik OK, thanks for the info, I also thought probably not being the only one in the world with this, lol ...

Comment: OK, now once again saw this 3.99TB Update cleaning bug after 3 months, on a just upgraded Windows 10 Home v1607 10.0.14393.447 laptop. But, this time it's still remaining and didn't yet see it disappearing, and didn't either dare to touch it for Update cleaning ...

Comment: Yes, OK, after several actions, shutdowns/restarts/defrags/disk cleanups etc. the 3.99TB bug wonder did finally vanish today, untouched ...